# Migrating _document.tsx to layout.tsx while handling "Extra attributes from the server"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I've earlier used `_document.tsx` to handle some script logic that needed to be very early. E.g. I might have dark mode code there to prevent flickering which might occur if doing `useEffect`.

**For example my `_document.tsx` might be:**

```js
import Document, { Head, Main, NextScript, Html } from "next/document";
import React from "react";

function presetTheme() {
  const dark = localStorage.getItem("theme") === "dark";

  if (dark) {
    document.body.classList.add("dark");
  }
}

const themeScript = `(() => { ${presetTheme.toString()}; presetTheme() })()`;

class MyDocument extends Document {
  render() {
    return (
      <Html lang={lang}>
        <Head />
        <body>
          <script dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: themeScript, }} />
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
      </Html>
    );
  }
}

export default MyDocument;
```

I now need similar functionality using Next 13.4+ with App Router and `layout.tsx`, still to run it early enough, but also to avoid/handle a warning I'm receiving.

**For example my `layout.tsx` might be:**

```js
import "../styles/global.css";

function presetTheme() {
  const dark = localStorage.getItem("theme") === "dark";

  if (dark) {
      document.body.classList.add("dark");
  }
}

const themeScript = `(() => { ${presetTheme.toString()}; presetTheme() })()`;

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body>
        <script dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: themeScript, }} />
        <div className="mx-auto px-4">
          {children}
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

Running with this `layout.tsx` gives me the following warning:

```
Warning: Extra attributes from the server: class
    at body
    at html
    at RedirectErrorBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/redirect-boundary.js:73:9)
    at RedirectBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/redirect-boundary.js:81:11)
    at NotFoundErrorBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/not-found-boundary.js:51:9)
    at NotFoundBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/not-found-boundary.js:59:11)
    at ReactDevOverlay (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/react-dev-overlay/internal/ReactDevOverlay.js:66:9)
    at HotReload (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/react-dev-overlay/hot-reloader-client.js:276:11)
    at Router (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/app-router.js:90:11)
    at ErrorBoundaryHandler (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/error-boundary.js:80:9)
    at ErrorBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/error-boundary.js:106:11)
    at AppRouter (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/app-router.js:374:13)
    at ServerRoot (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/app-index.js:154:11)
    at RSCComponent
    at Root (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/app-index.js:171:11)
```

The error I'm understanding occurs due to me adding `class="dark"` with the script that I run early to prevent dark mode flickering.

A couple of points of interest for me regarding this warning:

- Can I handle it more properly, to avoid the scenario?
- Is this a warning I can safely ignore taking my usage into account?
- Does the warning indicate any kind of performance impact?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve your flickering problem, you need to have the state set in the server. Because, as long as you have the state set in the client, the client needs to download the script first, and then change the theme, leading to the flickering problem.

One way to solve this is to use cookies.

> The cookies function allows you to read the HTTP incoming request cookies from a Server Component
>
> https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/cookies

Which means, rather than storing the theme in `localStorage`, you store it in a cookie.

You then need to modify your `_document.tsx` to read the theme from the cookie, like shown below:

```
import Document, { Head, Main, NextScript, Html } from "next/document";
import { cookies } from 'next/headers'
import React from "react";

class MyDocument extends Document {
  const dark = cookies().get('theme') === 'dark'

  render() {
    return (
      <Html lang="en">
        <Head />
        <body className={dark ? "dark" : ""}>
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
      </Html>
    );
  }
}

export default MyDocument;
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll try it in my code base and get back to you.

Comment: From some attempts using this I'll accept it since it still solves flickering and can be used without error. I'll just note that to my understanding as of now, it does require (opt in to) dynamic rendering. See e.g. https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/server-components#server-rendering-strategies

Answer (score 1):

This issue is because of `localStorage` in `presetTheme()`.

> While rendering your application, there was a difference between the React tree that was pre-rendered from the server and the React tree that was rendered during the first render in the browser (hydration).
>
> https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/react-hydration-error

`localStorage.getItem("theme")` will be different on server render vs client render. Hence, Next.js reports this error.

You can solve this by using `useState` and `useEffect` hooks, which are executed only during client render.

```
import "../styles/global.css";

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  const [themeScript, setThemeScript] = useState('')
 
  useEffect(() => {
    const presetTheme = () => {
      const dark = localStorage.getItem("theme") === "dark";

      if (dark) {
        document.body.classList.add("dark");
      }
    }

    setThemeScript(`(() => { ${presetTheme.toString()}; presetTheme() })()`)
  }, [])

  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body>
        <script dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: themeScript, }} />
        <div className="mx-auto px-4">
          {children}
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This does solve the error, but unfortunately it will flicker on startup when in dark mode.

Comment: Yes, as long as you are using client component, flickering will be present.

Comment: @HalvorHolstenStrand There are ways to handle the flickering, but not solve it. Let me know if you want to know.

Comment: The current answers doesn't resolve all my issues. Ideal scenario: No flickering. No errors. My current understanding is that I'd probably have to rewrite with use of cookies, because they can be read server-side and prevent hydration issues. I think that would be sufficient. If you want you could provide such an answer and I would accept it. I'll just note that I'm not super excited about using cookies, but it doesn't cause flickering or errors from my understanding.

Comment: @HalvorHolstenStrand Let me see how to solve that. Will update my answer.

Comment: If you want you can post another answer. I think this answer does provide a common way of doing it, it just still has flickering. I would upvote and accept a cookie answer as a separate solution.